# spring boot doesn't autowire inhert abstract class containing transactional method

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

now I have problem about dependency injection with abstract class.
Below sudo code is now I'm struggling point.

```
abstract class A { 
}

@Component
class B: A() {
}
```

When I autowire beans like

```
private val services: List<A>
```

This works but when I add some methods that annotated @Transactional,

```
@Component
class B: A() {
    @Transactional
    fun someMethod() {
    }
}
```

Then component B is not injected anymore.
Even if I add transactional method on abstract class and override, it doesn't work.
What should I do to use transactional method with abstract class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with specify @Transactional annotation both abstract class and concrete class, and remove @Transactional on methods.

Then dependency injection worked and Transactional worked fine.